# How to Change Oracle Encoding to AL32UTF8 in SQLPlus in Windows

Tags: oracle

Iused the following command to test my Oracle current encoding

```
select userenv('language') from dual;
select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
select * from nls_database_parameters
select * from nls_instance_parameters
select * from nls_session_parameters
```

[image]

But what I want is AL32UTF8. How to change the encoding to AL32UTF8. Thanks~

Comment: According to your comment you like to insert Korean characters to your database. Character set `WEMSWIN1252` does not support such characters. Either use `NVARCHAR2`, resp. `NCLOB` data type columns (typically `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` supports Unicode) or migrate character set of you database properly, see [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Open your console

```
sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup mount;
SQL> alter session set sql_trace=true;
SQL> alter system enable restricted session;
SQL> alter system set job_queue_processes=0;
SQL> alter system set aq_tm_processes=0;
SQL> alter database open;

//For version before oracle 9i like 8i, using these two lines
SQL> alter database character set internal_use UTF8;
SQL> alter database national character set internal_use UTF8;
//For version after oracle 9i, using these two lines
SQL> alter database character set internal_use AL32UTF8;
SQL> alter database national character set internal_use AL32UTF8;

SQL> alter session set sql_trace=false;
SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup;
```

Comment: Wow, wow... hold on.  This looks dangerous.  Aren't there many Oracle manual chapters and tools dedicated to changing database character sets?  I don't think it's this easy.  And it looks like the question was just about a client issue, not necessarily a server issue.

Comment: This does not answer the question. You provided an instruction how to destroy (potentially) your database, `alter database character set` is not supported anymore. (it was supported prior Oracle 10.1)

Comment: @JonHeller Thank you. I am a new bee to the Oracle. Do you have how to change the encoding of Oracle DB. If there is no need to change the encoding, how to insert Korean to my DB.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you. I am a new bee to the Oracle. Do you have how to change the encoding of Oracle DB. If there is no need to change the encoding, how to insert Korean to my DB.

Comment: @Zetian If the issue isn't just with the client (that is, if Wernfried's excellent answer doesn't fully resolve the issue), but you don't want to go through the difficulty of converting the database character set, you may want to look into using `NVARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR2` data types for some columns.  An `NVARCHAR2` will use the database's national character set, which is usually UTF16.  It's not as convenient as having the database use UTF8 naturally, but it may be the best option some times.

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways to set it.

- As Environment Variable `NLS_LANG`. Either temporarily with

  `SET NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` or in your Computer Property settings.
- In your Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG`, resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` for an 32-bit Oracle Client on Windows 64-bit.

In case you set both the Environment variable takes precedence.

Please note, when you set `NLS_LANG` value then you just tell the Oracle database "my client uses character set AL32UTF8" - it does not necessarily mean that your client is really using AL32UTF8!

In case of SQL*Plus it inherits the character set from `cmd.exe` codepage. You can interrogate and change it with command `chcp`, e.g.

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 850

C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>sqlplus ...
```

See [Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a list of code pages.

However, according to your screenshot you use Java based SQL Developer. SQL Developer does not depend on `NLS_LANG` setting. Check value in Tools -> Preferences -> Environment -> Encoding.